# [Q/KDB+]: wsfull when creating splayed table from csv using `.Q.fs`

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a ***9.6GB*** csv file from which I would like to create an on-disk splayed table.

When I run this code, my 32-bit q process (on Win 10, 16GB RAM machine) runs out of memory (`'wsfull`) and crashes after creating an incomplete 4.68GB splayed table (see the screenshot).

```
path:{` sv (hsym x 0), 1_x}
symh: {`$1_ string x}

colnames: `ric`open`high`low`close`volume`date
dir: `:F:

db: `db
tbl: `ohlcv
tbldisk: path dir,db,tbl
tblsplayed: path dir,db,tbl,`
dbsympath: symh path dir,db
csvpath: `:F:/prices.csv

.Q.fs[{ .[ tblsplayed; (); ,; .Q.en[path dir,db] flip colnames!("SFFFFID";",")0:x]}] csvpath
```

---

What exactly is going on in the memory and on the disk behind the scene when reading the csv file with `.Q.fs` and `0:`? Is the csv read row by row or column by column?

I thought that only the [132kB chunks](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qfsn-streaming-algorithm) are held in the memory at any given time, hoping that `.Q.fs` is `'wsfull` resistant.

Is the q process actually taking in the whole column (splay) into memory, one at a time, as it increments the chunks?

Considering that: (according to this [source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7522327), among others):

> on 32-bit systems the main memory OLTP portion of a database is
>   limited to about 1GB of raw data, i.e. 1/4 of the address space

that would nearly explain running out of memory. As shown on this screenshot taken right after the `'wsfull`, couple of columns are near the 1GB limit.

[image]

Here is a run with memory profiling:

```
.Q.fs[{ 0N!.Q.w[]; .[ tblsplayed; (); ,; .Q.en[path dir,db] flip colnames!("SFFFFID";",")0:x]}] csvpath
```

[image]

Comment: what's the sym file size?

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin 336kB when `'wsfull` kicks in

Comment: re your point about q mapping whole columns it might be interesting to attach windbg to the process and set a breakpoint at CreateFileMapping and log its inputs

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin interesting, however that's quite an advanced level for me, unless I know step by step instructions how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's row by row when Q reads a csv. The reason your q session crashes is probably because you didn't clear memory during

```
.Q.fs[{ .[ tblsplayed; (); ,; .Q.en[path dir,db] flip colnames!("SFFFFID";",")0:x]}] csvpath
```

Try to add [.Q.gc[]](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/dotq/#qgc-garbage-collect)

```
.Q.fs[{ .Q.gc[]; .[ tblsplayed; (); ,; .Q.en[path dir,db] flip colnames!("SFFFFID";",")0:x]}] csvpath
```